# NGINX: Rewrite root and forward get params

Tags: nginx

i can't figure out how to do the following with nginx:

- http://example.com -> http://new.example.com
- http://example.com?a=1 -> http://new.example.com?a=1
- http://example.com/sub -> no redirection

Thanks,
Gerold

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/converting_rewrite_rules.html

And this one is useful too:

https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/